# Popup Div HTML5 using only CSS and basic/pure javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html, popup

**Please note:** With my site host company, jQuery (very unfortunately) is **NOT** an option for me and I cannot link to **external** JS or CSS files. My popup div contains the **CSS AND JS** code in the "head" section of my webpages as a workaround.

My problem hopefully requires just a simple update/adjustment of my existing JS. The popup Div (for the Contact Form) on my site which was functioning 100% correct (except for position:fixed issues in IE I had gave up on for the moment) just a week ago. Well my hosting company just switched over to HTML5 (from "DTD 4.01 Transitional" I believe) and now my popup div is no longer functioning correctly in ANY browser (IE9, FF, Chrome, Safari), some worse than others.

The issues to fix are (please go to my website http://solitairethahalo.com to see it in action):

- **FIXED** *(all 4 browsers)* "line-height" html tag I used to format the contact form instructions/info no longer works; as a result the "Form" div class is now larger than the div container height
- **75% FIXED** *(Firefox & IE)* positioning is incorrect; popup appears at bottom of screen so that only a small portion of the popup's header is visible
- **50% FIXED** *(all 4 browsers)* my existing popup never had the code for it, but I would like for the popup div to remain centered/fixed when the browser window is resized if possible

**I can't paste my existing code properly, so I made it accessible thru my website: http://solitairethahalo.com/popupdiv.txt**

Please provide (you can email me as necessary) a revised HTML5-compliant version of my existing code if possible.

Thanks!

---

**UPDATES:**

- Line-height: After looking it up and getting an idea, I fixed the problem by simply changing  to . Glad it was simple.
- Popup positioning & resizing: The positioning error is fixed with a slight adjustment to my existing code. Using js code from a comment below allowed me to get the desired re-positioning of the popup upon window resizing. However, I've been unable to make the modal window function with that code. So for now, I've reverted to my own revised code that currently lacks the re-size re-position functionality, but I'm working on it still.

Comment: Can't you just change the host? No JS is NOT an option would mean to me: This very Hosting company is NOT and option to me.

Comment: Your page contains links to stylesheets, javascript and jquery but you say you can't do that. Don't understand.

Comment: @Rob, all of those nice links are provided within my host company's templates. But on the user end, one cannot utilize such links or jquery for non-template elements. *(They even have popup contact form templates that are great if you don't need to edit them at all)*. There's a valid reason; my host company specializes in "easy, unexperienced-user friendly" design. So while designing using my host's site builder is extremely easy and requires no knowledge of coding, the downside is that those who do want to do custom/complex editing are hindered by the builder's limitations.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use any JS then its possible in only one way.

You can do one thing, Either for popup replace it with sliding panel. 
Add your popup div inside "contact" div. And from CSS3 on mouseover of your "contact" div, use css3 transition and set its position left to show popup.

This will work in all browsers. Animation wont work in IE8 or lesser.

Comment: IE 9 has transform but no transition

Comment: oh yes. In short without using javascript with pure CSS, only this you can offer.

Comment: @ParagGajjar....Clarification: I **can** use JS, I just can't link to **external** JS files. My current code, if you view the "popupdiv.txt" file I linked to at the bottom of my initial question post, contains a decent amount of JS that was in popup div template I used.

**So how would I adjust my existing JS to comply with HTML5 rules?**

Comment: @yunzen I completely get what you're saying. But my funds are limited right now and I get a full year of free basic/limited hosting with this company, which is good enough for now. I have plenty of experience in working around limited funds/resources in various situations, so this is just another one of those situations I must work through

Comment: Also, I tried for a quick moment to experiment with CSS transitions/animations, but with no luck. I do emphasize that it was a very quick experiment, but animation is not a necessity so I didn't spend much time on it. If CSS animation code (such as fade in) is indeed a simple task however, please do tell me how to add it to my existing CSS....Animation isn't a priority though. Adjusting my JS to work with HTML5 is my top concern, so that I can get my popup div to work again. Popup div properly functioning, **1st**; aesthetic CSS animation, 2nd.....THANKS!

Comment: Am I supposed to replace ALL of my existing JS with the code you provided @ParagGajjar? Doing so doesn't fix it, well to be exact, the popup doesn't even pop up so I don't know if the positioning is corrected or not. I tried about 13 times to implement your code into my existing code with no luck.....There isn't any way to adjust a few lines/values in my existing code at all?

Comment: UPDATE: I had to make an adjustment to the "open" command code to get the popup to open. **It is working now** for the most part (it's slightly off center when I resize the browser window, but I don't care, it works good enough). **However**, it only works for the popup div itself and the modal window that I have doesn't even appear now. I'm doing some trial-and-error editing to see if I can get the modal window to show up as well.

Comment: @ParagGajjar, I didn't have any luck with the modal window using your code. Any way you can provide the lines of code I need for the modal to function?

Comment: Are you talking about "What is Image Verification ( Captcha )?" popup window?

For this you have to change your code: 

window.open('http://www.emailmeform.com/captcha-instruction.html','_blank','width=400, height=500, left=' + (screen.width /2 - 225) + ', top=100');return false;

Comment: No...if you go back to my site and open the popup Contact Form, a transparent "modal" window appears and creates a dimming effect on all webpage contents in the entire window, except for the popup Contact Form of course which sits on top of everything. I couldn't figure out how to make this "modal" window appear with your code.

Comment: See this: http://jsfiddle.net/parag1111/h5wGs/3/  I've added background color in CSS for model. You can assign transparent PNG or CSS3 opacity feature.

Comment: OK, that is similar to what I attempted. I guess I had something in the wrong spot. I will let you know how it works for me (looks good in the jsfiddle sample). Thanks!

Comment: First attempt at the revised code (from jsfiddle.net/parag1111/h5wGs/3) was unsuccessful. I'll fiddle with it some more and see if I just didn't implement it right.

Comment: Make sure that content inside your popup object doesn't have bigger width than desired popup width.